# Found a folder named '~' in my home dir. Should I be worried?

Tags: directory, home-directory, malware, hacking

I just found a folder named: `~` in my home directory. It had a little red cross on its bottom right corner,like root folder have. It was empty. When I deleted it, I was prompted to enter my login password twice (back to back). Should I be worried, like of some virus or being hacked.

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure you didin't try to create a directory using `sudo`? Like `sudo mkdir ~ `?

Comment: @ schrodigerscatcuriosity Yes I did not create a directory like that. Recently I installed just installed Okular application.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, I just tried ```sudo mkdir ~```, and it gave ```cannot create directory ‘/home/prateek332’: File exists```. But no file named ```~``` exists in home, I checked hidden files as well.

Comment: You should be VERY careful with a directory named ~, and in a terminal, always use a full path name when referring to it -- e.g. ls /home/prateek332/~ because the bash shell  treats ~ as your home directory.  Luckily the mkdir failed because of your existing directory, if it succeeded, you would have just wiped out your home directory.